# Discord command not working as expected to with category

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to make a command that lets you move a channel into a category or create one if that name isn't there when using a command it works but it only moves 1 to 1 category. I want it to allow me to move more than one channel to a single category. Here is the code:

````
const { error } = require("console");
const { channel } = require("diagnostics_channel");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { create } = require("domain");

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "MESSAGE_CONTENT"],
    partials: ["CHANNEL", "MESSAGE"]
});

const token = ("MTE3NzYxNjUxOTIyNDYzNTUzMg.G9glxT.4PR8TfThgM0rPqghyFrZvGVnr4R_R3I8s1FIJw") // your bot token here

client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log(`Client has been initiated! ${client.user.username}`)
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
        if (message.content.startsWith('!category')) {
        const args = message.content.split(' ');
        const categoryName = args[1];
        let category = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === categoryName && c.type === 'GUILD_CATEGORY');
        if (!category) {
        category = await message.guild.channels.create(categoryName, { type: 'GUILD_CATEGORY' });
        message.channel.send("Successful!");
        await message.channel.setParent(category.id);
    }
}});

client.login(token);```
````

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be showing us your bot token so I recommend that you change that ASAP.

Second, your code is moving the channel where the message originates from to the category you've chosen.

To move more than one channel, you're going to have to have to use a loop.

For example if you want to move all the channels from the parent category of the channel you sent your message in, you could do something like this:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    let parentId;
    let targetParent = ""; //Add your target category here

    parentId = message.channel.parentId;

    if (!parentId) {
        return;
    }

    let parent = message.guild.channels.cache.get(parentId);

    for (let [key, channel] of parent.children.cache) {
        await channel.setParent(targetParent);
    }
}
```

Comment: well basically how i want is fo rexample if I say !category blah blah it'll make a category with that name and move all channels to it

Comment: I'll assume that the part of your original code to create the channel if !category condition works. Then you just need to insert the for loop that I made in your if condition to transfer the channels to that newly created category.